# UDP python listener doesn't work with UDP cpp server

Tags: python, c++, sockets, udp

I implemented both UDP clients and servers in python and in cpp.
The cpp listener catches the messages from the cpp server, the python listener catches the messages from the python server, but when I'm running the cpp server and the python client, it just keep waiting for messages or raise a timeout exception (when using the sock.settimeout() option).

Here is how I'm sending messages in the cpp UDP server:

```
groupAddress = QHostAddress(serverIP);
udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
QByteArray datagram  = QByteArray::number(someIntNumber)
udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), groupAddress, portNumber);
```

The works perfectly using this cpp listener:

```
groupAddress = QHostAddress(serverIP);
udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, serverPort, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress);
connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));

void StreamingClientThread::processDatagrams()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        printf("%s \n",datagram.data());
    }
}
```

But doesn't work using this python implementation of the UDP listener:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('', PORT)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(server_address)
next_val = sock.recv(2048)
```

I also check both listeners "signature" in netstat, and they both looks the same:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:45454
```

Where 45454 is the port I'm listening to. 
The same listener does work when using the following python implpemention for the UDP server:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('localhost', port_numder)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.sendto(data_to_send, server_address)
```

Any idea why the python listener doesn't work with the cpp server?

Comment: are you sure both listeners are not running at the same time (ok that's far-fetched).

Comment: Yes, I double-checked that :)

Comment: cpp implementation seems to be multicast, python implementation seems to be unicast. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: You are right! I've just found here (https://pymotw.com/2/socket/multicast.html) how to listen to the multicast.
I hope this will do the trick!